Dependency Injection and Sub-Dependencies
I have a basic scenario where class A has dependency class B which has dependency class C.
Class A needs to use methods of both class B and class C.
Is it a best practice to inject both class B and class C into class A?
Or is it just as well for class B to offer a getter that returns class C?
For the sake of this question, we can assume the class C instance is going to be injected from the same place and is expected to be shared regardless of how it gets into class A.

General architecture questions like this are more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se].

In short yes. The SOLID principles dictate that injecting dependencies is a requirement. There is more to it though. SOLID also says that a class should not depend on a concrete implementation, but instead an abstraction like an interface.
So specifically, you likely need to have an interface for B and C, as well as implementations. Class A would type-hint against the interfaces for B and C, while at runtime the implementations for B and C are injected.
It sounds like you are looking into autowiring which is a great way to handle dependency management.

Just to clarify, because this was not a yes/no question, are you saying that allowing Class C to provide Class B to Class A is not an equally good solution?  Even if the interface for Class B specifies a readable property of type/interface Class C?
